# Checking for keys in a map function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am looking to return a string if a key isnt avaiable within a map function. This is my current function, where sometimes it would be unable to find the key `edBidResponse` and return an Error.

```
const winCpm = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result.response.response.edBidResponse.responseObject.winCpm);
};
```

When an API is called sometimes `.result.response.response.` will not have an `edBidResponse` object. As an example shows...

**With**

id like to return `data.map((result) => result.response.response.edBidResponse....`

```
"response": {
            "response": {
                "defLevel": "xxxx",
                "reason": "yyy",
                "edBidResponse": { ...
```

**Without**

Id like to return a string "Empty Value" For each value where `edBidResponse` was not present.

```
"response": {
            "response": {
                "defLevel": "xxx",
                "reason": "yyy",
                "logEvent": [...
```

I have tried many if statements but nothing seems to click, i have read some SO stuff on `reduce` but never used that. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you change your map function to simply include a conditional test, returning one thing if result.response.response.edBidResponse is defined and another thing if not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for checking if a property has existed or not.

The optional chaining will return `undefined` in whichever depth it fails to detect a property does not exist. For example, if the `result` has no `response` property then it returns `undefined` except throwing an error.

```js
const winCpm = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result?.response?.response?.edBidResponse?.responseObject?.winCpm || 'Some fallback string');
};
```

Comment: Genius! Must learn to use those `?` more. This is perfect...nice and clean too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do few things. This solution can work for you.

```
     const winCpm = () => {
      return data.map((result) => result.response.response.edBidResponse ? 
        result.response.response.edBidResponse.responseObject.winCpm : 'Empty value');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get method from lodash if you have lodash installed.

The first argument is the data, the second argumet is the path and the third is the default value.

```js
const winCpm = () => {
    return data.map((result) =>
      _.get(result, 'response.response.edBidResponse.responseObject.winCpm', '');
    };
    console.log()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use if and else :

```
 const winCpm = () =>
      data.map(result => {
        if (result.response.response.edBidResponse)
          return result.response.response.edBidResponse.responseObject.winCpm
        else return 'Empty Value'
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
import _ from "lodash"

const winCpm = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((result) => {
        let res = result.response.response
        if(_.has(res, 'edBidResponse')){
          ... do stuff accordingly
        }
        else{
          ..other code..
        }

      })}
    </>
  )
};
```